# How do I use the second Value constructor in gdb's python API?

Tags: python, gdb, gdb-python

In gdb's [Values From Inferior documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Values-From-Inferior.html#index-Value_002e_005f_005finit_005f_005f-1), there's a second constructor for creating objects within python.  It states:

> Function: `Value.__init__ (val, type)`
>
>   This second form of the
>   `gdb.Value`
>   constructor returns a
>   `gdb.Value`
>   of type
>   `type`
>   where the value contents are taken from the Python buffer object specified by
>   `val`
>   . The number of bytes in the Python buffer object must be greater than or equal to the size of type.

My question is, how do I create a buffer object that I can pass into the constructor?  For instance, if I wanted to create a string (yes, I know that the first Value constructor can do this, but this is an example) I wrote the following function:

```py
  def make_str(self, str):
    str += '\0'
    s = bytearray(str.encode())
    return gdb.Value(s, gdb.lookup_type('char').array(len(str)))
```

However, when I tried to use it, I got the message:

```
Python Exception <class 'ValueError'> Size of type is larger than that of buffer object.:
```

How would I make a buffer object that I could pass into the Value constructor?  What would I need to do to generate a Value object?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm. Seems to be an off by one error since this worked:

```py
  def make_str(self, str):
    str += '\0'
    s = bytearray(str.encode())
    return gdb.Value(s, gdb.lookup_type('char').array(len(s)-1))
```

Which is strange, I would have expected the array length to be the length of the string, not one less.

Comment: It looks weird, but this is on purpose: "If one argument is given, it is the inclusive upper bound of the array; in this case the lower bound is zero"
https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Types-In-Python.html#Types-In-Python

Comment: @AlexanderFasching, ah yes.  Thx.  Missed that line.